# Is it possible to draw simple diagrams with LaTeX/LyX?

Tags: lyx, technical-drawing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to generate a nice function graph in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-graph-in-latex)
>   [How to draw Venn diagrams (especially: complements) in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex)

I wonder instead of images, can I have LaTeX/LyX draw simple diagrams like sets, graphs for me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For Venn diagrams: [How to Draw Venn Diagrams, Especially Complements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex). For graphs: [Best way to generate a nice function graph in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-graph-in-latex)

Comment: @Jake, awesome, but that should be an answer! Please create an answer then I can mark it answered

Comment: Glad it helps. Links to other answers are usually given as comments, instead of answers, to avoid duplicating the information. We'll probably close this question as a duplicate of the two I linked to, so it will act as an entry point for others searching for the topic.