# Lyx edit source code otherwise, How to insert diagrams

Tags: lyx, sourcecode, technical-drawing

Is it possible to edit source code in Lyx?

Otherwise, how might I draw diagrams like [venn diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex) or [graphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-graph-in-latex)

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer is no, though you can export the file to LaTeX and work from there.

Re. second question, you can insert any TeX code in LyX by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (TeX button).

Answer (score 1):

here is an example: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=LyX/lyx

Comment: I think the community agreed that questions should not just contain links to other sites: "the solution should be entered in the text of the answer itself. Attributions to external sources are fine – and encouraged! – but just linking to solutions posted elsewhere outside of the site should be discouraged." (from [Quality Standards for Answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/quality-standards-for-answers))