# Packages to plot functions such as the logistic function (or "S-shaped function")?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Is it possible to plot the graph of an S-shaped function in LaTeX? If yes, then how? Which packages should I use for that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX, could you please provide what an S-shaped graph is? I must admit I have no clue what it is?

Comment: Please give a picture of what you mean. Also, it would be nice to post the code starting from `\documentclass{...}` and ending at `\end{document}` to show what you have tried and it will save those who want to help, some typing work and guessing.

Comment: Are you talking about the [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)?

Comment: For different ways to plot functions in latex see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3622/15925

Comment: yes i am talking about the graph of logistic functions.i.e. a non-linear s-shape function..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`pgfplots` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) is really handy for that type of graphs. I invite you to have a look at the documentation, which is really well written, with many detailed examples.

Note that, on this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

However, since you're a new TeX.SE user, I'd like to get you started with `pgfplots`. Below is some code that reproduces the graph available on [the Wikipedia page on the logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) (also called "S-shaped function").

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}%
    [
        grid=major,     
        xmin=-6,
        xmax=6,
        axis x line=bottom,
        ytick={0,.5,1},
        ymax=1,
        axis y line=middle,
    ]
        \addplot%
        [
            blue,%
            mark=none,
            samples=100,
            domain=-6:6,
        ]
        (x,{1/(1+exp(-x))});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`pgfplots` is already taken. Hence this is just a drawing using tikz as part of getting bored and had some time package (`\usepackage[bored]{freetime}`) :-). It is not up to scale.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=10cm]
    \tikzset{help lines/.style={color=blue!50}}
    \draw[step=1cm,help lines] (-6,0) grid (6,1);
    \draw[ultra thin,step=.5cm,help lines] (-6,0) grid (6,1);
    \foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6}{
      \draw[y=1cm,thick,blue] (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.2);
      \node[y=1cm] at (\x,-0.4) {\x};
    }
    \foreach \y in {0.5,1}{
      \draw[thick,blue] (0,\y) -- (-0.2,\y);
      \node at (-0.45,\y) {\y};
    }
    \coordinate (a) at (6,1);
    \coordinate (b) at (-6,0);
    \draw (b) edge[magenta,ultra thick,out=360,in=180,looseness = 1.7] (a);    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`tikz` also offers a `plot` facility, though it is not comparable with `pgfplots`. Following code is given just for illustration while it is always better to use `pgfplots` fot plots.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[color=magenta] plot[
            mark=none,
            samples=100,
            domain=-6:6,
        ] ({\x},{1/(1+exp(-\x))});;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```