# What do you use for plotting?

Tags: diagrams, plot, r, gnuplot

I use Latex now for about two years and have written a couple of larger documentations with it. When it comes to plotting (simple or complex, functions or data) I used gnuplot or R. The later more and more nowadays. Usually I export the plots to a high resolution png and include it as figure in the document.

I know that there are some packages around to plot in latex itself. However I've not tried that yet and I'm not sure if I should. Probably its best to just stick to R.

Therefore my questions:

- What is your preferred way of plotting simple and complex things in
  Latex?
- What is the best way to use an external plotting tool
  (gnuplot, R, ...)?

An example of plotting in Latex:
[Best way to generate a nice function plots in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-graph-in-latex)

Comment: An inserted picture will never beat `pgfplots`.

Comment: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Comment: I'm a huge fan (Disclaimer: I'm one of the co-authors :-D) of gnuplottex (and thus gnuplot): http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.pdf (simple examples included)

Comment: Your question provokes opinion-based answers and is too broad, in my point of view, but the answer must be **gnuplot** of course ;-)

Comment: To plot what ? This is very much like which keyboard is good ? Are you a coder, gamer what do you need? If you are happy with R stick to it. When you are stuck with R write here what you are stuck with.

Comment: The best way? Of course PSTricks!