# How to draw a picture in electrical circuit diagrams in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

Now, I'm having a electrical circuit diagrams, i don't know how to draw it's in GeoGebra, please help me, thank you.
[image]

Comment: This is done in pgfplots but do you have the functions for the plots? I suppose the values are precise.

Comment: One should probably use the scope environment to separate a tikz plot or pgfplot from the circuit diagram, due to the difference in scale and origin.

Comment: It should be possible to draw this with `pgfplots`. If you have the functions try yourself, a basic setup is shown in [Best way to generate a nice function graph in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3630), and the manual has extensive information. When you get to the point where you are unable to go any further, edit your question to include the code you have. (Including the functions you need to plot.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little example, using pgfplots package, you can check the following in the package documentation:

Line styles p165, 4.7.2 Line Styles;
Nodes p190, 4.9 Axis Description;

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=3,
axis y line=left,
axis x line=middle,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
yticklabels=\empty,
ymax=1,
ymin=-1,
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,
domain=-5:5,samples=40]
{cos(deg(2*x))};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=3,
xticklabels=\empty,
yticklabels=\empty,
axis y line=left,
axis x line=middle,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
ymax=1,
ymin=-1,
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,dashed,
domain=-5:5,samples=40]
{cos(deg(3*x))};
\end{axis}


\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=3,
xticklabels=\empty,
yticklabels=\empty,
ymax=1,
ymin=-1,
axis y line=left,
axis x line=middle,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
yticklabels={,-5$\sqrt{3}$,},
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,dotted,
domain=-5:5,samples=40]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```