# Shading the area bounded by graphs in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

Thanks to [Torbjørn T.'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263991/3235) at [Best way to generate a nice function plots in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-plots-in-latex), there is an easy way to show multiple graphs using TikZ's `datavisualization`. Is there a way to shade i.e. fill in the region bounded by these graphs?

Comment: An MWE of the two functions on one axis would be useful.

Comment: As an aside, if you're not locked to the `datavisualization` library, you could look at `pgfplots`. Search the site for e.g. [`[pgfplots] fill between`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpgfplots%5D+fill+between)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[name path=f] {x^2 - x +4}; 
    \addplot[name path=g] {x^2 - x}; 
    \addplot [
        fill=blue, 
        fill opacity=0.2
    ]
    fill between[
        of=f and g
    ];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it with `datavisualization`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that part of your question.