# How can I plot a sigmoidal plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a sigmoidal graph like the one in the link below:

https://ibb.co/knbFjR

Could you please help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome. There are various options, perhaps most popular is `pgfplots`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-plots-in-latex for a code example.

Comment: Perhaps you learnt how to and that's why you can? How can we tell why you have this ability? Surely you are in a better position to judge the cause than us!

Comment: It is better to show what you tried yourself before to ask for help ...

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an idea.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=-2:2, 
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$\pi^0$},
    ytick={},yticklabels={},
    xtick={-1,0,1,2,3},xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5}
  ] 
    \addplot[mark=none,thick] ({tanh(\x)},{\x}); 
    \addplot[mark=none] ({sign(\x)*pow(abs(tanh(\x)),2/3)},{\x}); 
    \addplot[mark=none,dashed] ({sign(\x)*pow(abs(tanh(\x)),1/3)},{\x}); 
    \addplot[mark=none,domain=0.965:3,samples=60,thick] ({\x},{pow(\x-0.965,1/4)+2}); 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, I don't think this is a sigmoidal plot, but as you can see you can plot tanh functions here.