# Including Function Plots in a thesis

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I am currently writing on thesis, where I plan to include quite a few function plots. The functions I am talking about are mostly polynomial functions (domain and range are real numbers). However, I also have a few piecewise defined functions I also want to include in the thesis.

My question is, would you rather create the function plots in an external program like matlab and include them as a pdf or jpeg, or would you create the plots within   LaTeX? What would be the benefits for me in any of these scenarios? Furthermore, if i chose to create my function plots in LaTeX, what would you use for this purpose?

Comment: Take a look at `tikz` and `pgf` packages. The bigger advantage of creating in LaTeX (except of the need of only one LaTeX document's code and not separate software to edit everything) is that the same font and an appropriate font and fontsize will be added in your document. This makes the document been really professional.

Comment: Hi, welcome. The most popular package for plotting functions is likely `pgfplots`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-plots-in-latex?rq=1

Comment: Depending on the plot, I would create them in LaTeX independent files as pdfs, and include them via `include graphics`. I a plot is not quite what you want, it's easier and faster to modify, without changing the main files. To plot within laTeX, the usual tools are either `pstricks` or `TikZ`.

Comment: I've written a document with several plots of (multivariable) functions from `pgfplots`. The compilation time became incredibly high with more plots, so I decided to include the graphics (made by, e. g., MATLAB or in other `LaTeX` documents). I don't know whether it would be better if I wrote the chapters part by part and include them later$\dots$, so I would recommend you to try both options.